# Use Variable as optional input in enumerate

Tags: environments, enumerate, enumitem, optional-arguments

Can anyone tell me how to fix the following problem:

The following code produces the error

> Package enumitem Error: topsep=0em,partopsep=0em undefined

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\def \ListSimpleArguments {topsep=0em,partopsep=0em}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[\ListSimpleArguments]
    \item aaa
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

But when I do not use the Variable \ListSimpleArguments then it works:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\def \ListSimpleArguments {topsep=0em,partopsep=0em}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[topsep=0em,partopsep=0em]
    \item aaa
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

How can I solve this problem? How can I define these optional arguments in a variable?

Answer (score 3):

The parsers of key=value syntax take care *not* to expand macros. It is better to use the facilities of the package to set the defaults:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{topsep=0em,partopsep=0em}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item aaa
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```